# tagger = perceptron tagger() traceback error

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

```
from nltk.tag.perceptron import PerceptronTagger

tagger = PerceptronTagger()

def pos_tagging(X):
    tagset = None
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(X)
    tags = nltk.tag._pos_tag(tokens, tagset, tagger)
    pos_X = map(get_wordnet_pos, tags)
    return pos_X
```

**AI.py is my python file**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/jpsamaranayake/PycharmProjects/AI/AI.py", line 206, in <module>

 tagger = PerceptronTagger()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\perceptron.py", line 141, in __init__
    self.load(AP_MODEL_LOC)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\perceptron.py", line 209, in load
    self.model.weights, self.tagdict, self.classes = load(loc)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 801, in load
    opened_resource = _open(resource_url)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 924, in _open
    return urlopen(resource_url)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 454, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1265, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)

urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: c>
```

Comment: with out sample code we can't help you

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @The6thSense i uploaded the code

Comment: @Forge  i uploaded the code

Comment: @Janukasamaranyake did you run the `nltk.download() ` before doing all this ?

Comment: @The6thSense Yes i DO

Comment: Can you post the output of `python3 -c 'import nltk; print(nltk.__version__); print(nltk.data.path)'` in your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the nltk version to 3.1 and delete previous avareage perceptron tagger in nltk.download() and install it again